# Riemann sum with negative coefficient and positive literal

Tags: calculus, integration, functions, riemann-integration, interval-arithmetic

## $ f(x)=x^2-1$ with an interval of $[0,1]$

i have this equation and made each step to solve this problem, but at the time of applying the special rule when $\sum_{k=1}^{n}k^2= \frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6}$ but i think i messed up a value in my equations because i got a value that doesn't match with the one in my guidebook, here are my steps, please try to explain where i got wrong please, thank you.

[here is my work since LATEX is pretty hard rn for me at the moment.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CASCO.jpg)

Comment: if anyone needs to see each step i made i can modify the post in order to show it.

Comment: we can't tell you what you did wrong without seeing what you did

Comment: already put my steps in order to check it, i will appreciate if someone saw it.

Comment: I don't understand what you did (and I'm sure I'm not the only one), $\int_0^1 f(x)dx=\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow +\infty}\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^nf\left(\frac{k}{n}\right)$, is this your definition of the integral ?

Comment: yes it is, sorry if it looks messy, latex is not my thing, i will try to scan the page in order to be more precise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$ \int_0^1 f(x)dx=\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow +\infty}\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^nf\left(\frac{k}{n}\right) $$
And
$$ \begin{aligned} \frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^nf\left(\frac{k}{n}\right)&=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n\left(\frac{k^2}{n^2}-1\right) \\
&=\frac{1}{n^3}\sum_{k=1}^n k^2-1 \\
&=\frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6n^3}-1
\end{aligned}$$
Letting $n\rightarrow +\infty$ gives $$ \int_0^1 f(x)dx=\frac{2}{6}-1=-\frac{2}{3} $$